# Is there any way to get a set of resources detailed information from Keycloak server by using Keycloak rest endpoints

Tags: authorization, keycloak, keycloak-services

we have rest point to get the resource information from keycloak server.

- http://{host}:{port}/auth/realms/{realm}/authz/protection/resource_set/{resource_id}

from this endpoint I can get only one resource information.

```
-{
    "name": "/TestResource",
    "type": "customer",
    "ownerManagedAccess": false,
    "displayName": "testresource",
    "_id": "****resource id****",
    "icon_uri": "testIconUri",
    "uris": [
        "/uri2",
        "/uri1"
    ],
    "resource_scopes": [
        {
            "name": "GET"
        }
    ]
 }
```

But, In my case i have more than 25 resources to be loaded in my menu of application.

If i go with above endpoint, i need to call the same service for more than 25 times . so i need some other way to get set of resources information using single endpoint.

I expect a solution for this,
thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. 
we can get all the authorization related details using

http://{host}:{port}/auth/admin/realms/{realmname}/clients/{clientId}/authz/resource-server/settings

provided by keycloak.

- we have to use admin credentials
- {clientId} is not the Client Name given by you. it is generated by keycloak for each client

Answer (score 1):

Keycloak 21

`/realms/{realm}/authz/protection/resource_set?first=0max=25&deep=true`

`deep=true` does the trick

`first` and `max` parameters can be used for pagination

`first` like OFFSET in SQL

`max` like LIMIT in SQL

Response should look like:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Default Resource",
        "type": "urn:my-client:resources:default",
        "owner": {
            "id": "f6474c23-65d7-4ac4-9921-e3abe17feb87",
            "name": "my-client"
        },
        "ownerManagedAccess": false,
        "attributes": {},
        "_id": "ff243bb5-8b00-4c57-8b18-3604cc687da5",
        "uris": [
            "/*"
        ]
    }
]
```